# Legal issues abou reinstalling notebook software

Tags: windows, installation, oem

I bought new Acer notebook. It comes with Windows 7 HP 64bit OEM.  But I would like to fresh install it, and make dualboot with Ubuntu.

So, first, if I reinstalled Windows for another legal version, will it destroy warranty? If I had for example a different OS installed, do I still have warranty on whole notebook?

And second, is there a way to reinstall OEM Windows? Like downloading same copy and use OEM CD-Key on it?

Because, let's say my OS gets damaged somehow, and I can reinstall it myself, but I dont wan't to lose waranty or OEM license, and wait month to get notebook fixed by RMA. Is there a legal way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not lose warranty because of changing the OS, however, be prepared that if you get a problem, the first thing they will probably do is recover the system to its original setup.

Also, they have every right not to support you against problems of hardware not working that is directly due to changing the OS where it would work otherwise (e.g. driver support).

You may get problems trying to reinstall the OS with a different media, it is best to keep a copy of the recovery media. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, there isn't really any logic behind it. It used to be only recovery disks but now, sometimes using generic media with the key works.

Comment: Hope you don't mind @Wil. I get OCD on such minor stuff

Comment: @Sathya - No problem.... Always feel free to edit my answers! I don't know what's wrong with me recently, I feel like my English skills are going down the drain!

Comment: How do you know about it?

Comment: @Richard - how do I know about what?

Comment: "You will not lose warranty because of changing the OS"

Comment: @Richard - because in most countries, warranty on the sales of goods is written in law - unless they can show that you did something to make the situation worse/did something bad on purpose, simply changing the OS or even installing a part will not void any warranty. If they did say so, then you come to a guy like me who will write a technical report and you would be able to take legal action against the company who says otherwise.